# How to pass a Makefile target to another

Tags: linux, makefile

so I have a large Makefile that runs all of my tests for my particular project. Each target is a different group of tests. The script will run the target, store its output into a temporary file.
Currently the target looks like this:

```
count:
# USE: make count test=<name of test to run>
# Save output to target 
        $(MAKE) $(test) > last_output.txt
        cat last_output.txt
# Print Passed
        @cat last_output.txt | { grep -E -w "SUCCESS|RELAX-PASS" || true; }
# Print Failed
        @cat last_output.txt | { grep -E -w "FAILED" || true; }
# Failed Count
        @echo "\e[1;31mFAILED:\e[1;37m"
        @cat last_output.txt | { grep -c "FAILED" || true; }
# Passed Count
        @echo "\e[1;32mPASSED:\e[1;37m"
        @cat last_output.txt | grep -E -c "SUCCESS|RELAX-PASS"
# Count all
        @echo "TOTAL: "
        @cat last_output.txt | { grep -E -c "FAILED|SUCCESS|RELAX-PASS" || true; }
```

And the instruction to execute it looks like:

```
make count test=add
```

What I was wondering was if I could not specify test= when I'm running the command so that it would look like this:

```
make count add
```

and then the add target will execute which looks like:

```
add:
         clear && run.pl add_0.asm
         clear && run.pl add_1.asm
         clear && run.pl add_2.asm
         clear && run.pl add_3.asm
         ect.
```

Comment: I don't know what this `clear` or `run` are supposed to do, but why can't you just write exactly what you've written here?

Comment: clear is just the basic linux clear screen command. And I wrote a pearl script called run so that is exactly what I have. @MadScientist

Comment: I guess I don't understand the question.  Why can't you just run `make add` then?  What exactly is the problem with what you have?  What does it do that you don't want it to do, or what doesn't it do that you do want it to do?

Comment: Right, so this count target I made will print a bunch of statistics on the tests (# of failures, # of passed, which ones passed, which ones failed) but since I have about 30 tests targests (add, sub, xor, bgez, ect) I don't want to add the code for the statistics for all 30 tests. I'll update count to give a better description.

Comment: So, @MadScientist, the only difference I want is when I'm calling the target count, I want to just do "make count <test to run>" instead of "make count test=<test to run>". I don't know if it is possible.

Comment: It's possible, but `make count_add` would be much easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every command line argument to make is either an option, a variable assignment, or a target.  There's no possible way to treat an argument as anything else.  So when you run `make check add`, the `add` will be a target that make will attempt to build and there's no way to have it be considered any other way.

As @Beta suggests if you are willing to embed to the test name into the target, like `make count_add`, then you can do this:

```
SHOW = \
    cat last_output.txt; \
    grep -E -w "SUCCESS|RELAX-PASS" < last_output.txt; \
    grep -E -w "FAILED" < last_output.txt; \
    echo "\e[1;31mFAILED:\e[1;37m"; \
    grep -c "FAILED" < last_output.txt; \
    echo "\e[1;32mPASSED:\e[1;37m"; \
    grep -E -c "SUCCESS|RELAX-PASS" < last_output.txt; \
    echo "TOTAL: "; \
    grep -E -c "FAILED|SUCCESS|RELAX-PASS" < last_output.txt;
    true

count:
        $(MAKE) $(test) > last_output.txt
        @$(SHOW)

count_%:
        $(MAKE) $* > last_output.txt
        @$(SHOW)
```

If you don't want to do that, the only possible solution is to use `ifeq` combined with `$(MAKECMDGOALS)` to break your makefile up into two sections: one that has a `.DEFAULT` target that does nothing (to ignore the extra targets like `add` etc.) and a second that runs those targets.